# How this API can get items of a JList (String)

Tags: java, swing, casting, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have a JList with a few items, Then I got an API that need to get the selected item and use it to provide some information about that item. My problem is that the type of the JList is String and the type of my API is obviously something different. Lets say LocationAPI. So the API gets index only from its own type and not other ones. I am looking for a solution to convert the selected item (String) to something suitable for the API. Here is a simple example of the API.

```
LinkedList<LocationAPI> stations = FetchWeatherForecast.findWeatherStationsNearTo("cityName");
for (LocationAPI station : stations) { System.out.println(station); }

// Assume the first match on the list is correct
LocationAPI firstMatch = stations.getFirst();

List<ForecastForOneDay> forecast = FetchWeatherForecast.getWeatherForecast(firstMatch);
```

So it is a simple example of how the API works, But Instead of 'firstMatch' and 'Station' I have to use my own items and lists. I got the Item and list, but I made them differently:

```
DefaultListModel<String> cityPlace = new DefaultListModel<String>();
JList myList = new JList(cityPlace);
```

So how can I use the items of the above list in the API??

Comment: Why don't you just use a `JList<LocationAPI>`

Comment: @Jeffrey Because it gets so complicated. The JList get filled by another window and changing that means changing the whole program.

Comment: @Jeffrey in fact I change all the JList and models to <LocationAPI> that error disappears. Thank you. But I get another error in compile. and pointing to the line that I make the 'firstMatch'. Here is that line: `LocationAPI` firstMatch = cityPlace.get(myList.getSelectedIndex());`